# show one custommer only

Tags: php, mysql, database, ms-query

i want to make a total sum of the ordered product for on custommer
how do i do that?

i have the following code

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT order_item_name, SUM(product_quantity) FROM wntl_virtuemart_order_items WHERE wntl_virtuemart_order_items.order_item_sku BETWEEN 2 and 2.9 AND order_status= 'U'  GROUP BY order_item_sku");   

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))   {   
echo "<tr>";   
echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['order_item_name'] . "</td>";    
echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['SUM(product_quantity)'] . "</td>";   
echo "</tr>";   
}
```

with this code i get a overall total
i want to see a total for one custommer

thx in advance grtz

Comment: What did you try so far? Also can you show us some database structure? I assume wntl_virtuemart_order_items table has a foreign key to customer or something?

Comment: you query is getting SUM for all customers in your table, not per customer

Comment: Need to see table structure before suggesting new query.

Comment: Stop. Acquaint yourself with any decent book or tutorial on php and mysql published withen, say, the last 3 years. Go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want counts by customer then you need to specify the customer id in `WHERE` condition.

E.g. if customer id is present in `wntl_virtuemart_order_items` table then your query will look like this:

```
SELECT order_item_name, SUM(product_quantity) 
FROM wntl_virtuemart_order_items 
WHERE wntl_virtuemart_order_items.order_item_sku BETWEEN 2 and 2.9 AND order_status= 'U' AND customer_id = ?
GROUP BY order_item_sku
```

If customer id is present in another table then you will need to use `JOIN` two tables like the below example:

```
SELECT order_item_name, SUM(product_quantity) 
FROM wntl_virtuemart_order_items JOIN wntl_virtuemart_orders ON wntl_virtuemart_order_items.virtuemart_order_id  = wntl_virtuemart_orders.virtuemart_order_id 
WHERE wntl_virtuemart_order_items.order_item_sku BETWEEN 2 and 2.9 AND wntl_virtuemart_order_items.order_status= 'U' AND wntl_virtuemart_orders.customer_number = ?
GROUP BY order_item_sku
```

Comment: hi if customer id is present in wntl_virtuemart_order_items table that is the problem its a other table: wntl_virtuemart_orders customer_number

Comment: Do you have any column that links these two tables?

Comment: virtuemart_order_id are on both

Comment: i have done: `code`$result = mysql_query
("

SELECT order_item_name, SUM(product_quantity) 
FROM wntl_virtuemart_order_items JOIN wntl_virtuemart_orders ON wntl_virtuemart_order_items.virtuemart_order_id=wntl_virtuemart_orders.virtuemart_order_id
WHERE wntl_virtuemart_order_items.order_item_sku BETWEEN 2 and 2.9 AND order_status= 'U' AND customer_id = 'PL8c62a61b3'
GROUP BY order_item_sku

"); `code` i get :Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: I have modified the query, have a look at the second query.

Comment: still error **bold**Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **bold**  

$result = mysql_query
("



SELECT order_item_name, SUM(product_quantity) 
FROM wntl_virtuemart_order_items JOIN wntl_virtuemart_order_items ON wntl_virtuemart_order_items.virtuemart_order_id  = wntl_virtuemart_order_items.virtuemart_order_id 
WHERE wntl_virtuemart_order_items.order_item_sku BETWEEN 2 and 2.9 AND order_status= 'U' AND wntl_virtuemart_order_items .customer_id = ?
GROUP BY order_item_sku

");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{

Comment: Can you try executing that query in MySQL console and see the output?

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, didn't get it :(

Comment: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'wntl_virtuemart_order_items'

Comment: #1052 - Column 'order_status' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: Change `order_status= 'U'` to `wntl_virtuemart_order_items.order_status= 'U'` and try again?

Comment: @edensanhardenberg could you please accept the answer if you think it has helped you?

Comment: @ Darshan how do i do that?